# What is the best way to handle 2 (or more) missing values in same row?

Tags: machine-learning, prediction, missing-data, k-nearest-neighbour, data-preprocessing

one of the methods to handle missing data is using `predictive model`.

If we have a row with 2 or more missing values, is it right (and accurate) to use `predictive model` ?

Suppose we have 40 features (column) and one of the rows have 2 missing values. (2 missing values and 38 not missing values)

So in order to use `predictive model` we need to predict each missing value with the other 38 columns (the columns with not missing values)

what will be better to do in that case ?

1. use predictive model ?
2. use knn ?
3. drop this row ?

Comment: It's a huge sub-field within statistics.  Have you read up on imputation methods?

Comment: yes, and I'm confused, so I ask this

Comment: Each approach has its pros and cons. There is no single or simple answer, I’m afraid. But multiple imputation is the most fascinating method.